# Xperia Neo V compatible earphones

Tags: headphones, impedance

I wanted to know if Sony XBA-3 earphones are compatible with Xperia Neo V phone?

Also, how to find out the output impedance on the phone's headphone jack? Will there be any need of amplifier? If yes, which one?

You may not answer all of those queries. Main concern is compatibility. :-)

Thanks in advance. Expecting some help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As far as audio goes, any headphones will work.  If you intend to use a headset with a built-in mic, you'll have to be sure it is set up with the OMTP TRRS layout.  See below...

[image: TRRS layout]

<sub>[source](http://talk.sonymobile.com/thread/62722)</sub>

Incidentally, there are also adapters ([here's an example on amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009HW15UG)) to swap the ground/mic ring/sleeve layout.  Of course, if you're handy at it, you could also swap the wires with a little solder work.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. I would like to know if any sound quality can get compromised if perfectly compatible earphones are not used?

Comment: @ivorykoder, sound quality would not be affected by using the other ring layout.  You'd just lose the ability to use the mic.

Comment: Okay. Understood. But what about impedance mismatch? Sony XBA 3 has impedance of 12 ohms. And I don't know what is the output impedance of my Xperia neo V phone. As I will be using those earphones with neo V, I want to get the best of it.

Comment: @ivorykoder, I cannot for the life of me, find any documentation on the output impedance of the neo V.  Not even on sony's white paper.  I did find a great article that goes into quite some detail [here](http://nwavguy.blogspot.com/2011/02/headphone-amp-impedance.html).  Basically, ideally, you want the output impedance to be no more than 1/8 the headphone's impedance.  In your case then, 1.5 Ohms.  That seems unlikely.  Give the article a read.  It may affect your decision about which headphones to purchase.  As far as the missing number, maybe call Sony?

Comment: I have also spent the same efforts understanding the impedance concept. Came to know from there only, that  impedance  must be 1/8th of ear phones impedance. And that's what bugged me. Because, 12 ohms is already low. neo V supported Bose MIE2 well which has 32 ohms impedance according to this [link](http://www.target.com/p/bose-mie2-audio-headphones-326223-0020/-/A-13038068#)'site'. But 32 is way greater than 12 ohms. :-|


I have the done a lot research about it. Even contacted helpdesk at Sony. The asked me to meet local retailer. Funny.


BTW Thanks for your time and efforts.

Comment: Was out of characters. Remaining words where, "Appreciate it. :-)"

Also, yes I will have audio call with Sony customer service by tomorrow. Otherwise, I am currently inclined to buy Bose MIE2.

Comment: @ivorykoder Upvote if that helps?

Comment: @Eugene S: Upvoted the answer. Although the answer did not help but the comments did. :-)

Comment: @ivorykoder Well, as long as it helps it's good :)